# Groovy AntBuilder, omit conditional attributes, like "setOmitNullAttributes" functionality on MarkupBulder

Tags: ant, attributes, groovy, builder

sample code:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.'antlib:org.jacoco.ant:agent'(
                enabled: enabled,
                property: 'agentvmparam')
```

When that "enabled" parameter is null, I'd like it to be not present in the ant task conversion, not merely "empty".  "empty" gets evaluated to "true" http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html#set-magic which isn't what I want.

xml builder example:

```
def xml = new MarkupBuilder()
xml.omitNullAttributes = true
xml.root(
        requiredAttribute:'required',
        optionalAttribute: optionalAttribute
        ) { }
```

That "omitNullAttributes" will ensure that the "optionalAttribute" xml element parameter isn't even present if the Groovy parameter evaluates to null.

so I get

```
<root requiredAttribute='required' />
```

instead of

```
<root requiredAttribute='required' optionalAttribute='' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a possible workaround, but does this work?

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.'antlib:org.jacoco.ant:agent'( [ enabled:enabled, 
                                     property:'agentvmparam' ].findAll { it.value != null } )
```

ie:  use a `findAll` to remove the null entries of the param map

Comment: Excellent!  Works fine, last long time.  Thanks!

Comment: A slight clarification on my description: in Ant "empty" gets evaluated to "false", but I needed it to be not evaluated at all so that default values can kick in