# Omit empty attributes with groovy DOMBuilder

Tags: dom, groovy, markupbuilder

Groovy's [MarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html) has an `omitNullAttributes` and an `omitEmptyAttributes`.  But [DOMBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/DOMBuilder.html) doesn't.  This is the code I have

```
>>> def xml = DOMBuilder.newInstance()
>>> def maybeEmpty = null
>>> println xml.foo(bar: maybeEmpty)
<foo bar=""/>
```

I want `bar` to be omitted if empty.  I found a workaround in an answer to [Groovy AntBuilder, omit conditional attributes...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692087/groovy-antbuilder-omit-conditional-attributes-like-setomitnullattributes-func) to `findAll` empty attributes and remove them.  Since I have a complex DOM to be generated, I'm looking for other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no built-in option for that, but if you need a DOMBuilder, you could subclass it and filter the attributes...

```
@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
class DOMBuilderSubclass extends groovy.xml.DOMBuilder {
    @Override
    protected Object createNode(Object name, Map attributes) {
        super.createNode name, attributes.findAll{it.value != null}
     }
}
```

You might want to tune the construction as in standard DOMBuilder, this is just an example.

```
def factory = groovy.xml.FactorySupport.createDocumentBuilderFactory().newDocumentBuilder()
def builder = new DOMBuilderSubclass(factory)
println builder.foo(bar: null, baz: 1)
//<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
//<foo baz="1"/>
```

standard output as you said was...

```
println groovy.xml.DOMBuilder.newInstance().foo(bar: null, baz: 1)
//<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
//<foo bar="" baz="1"/>
```