# Omit empty elements with groovy StreamingMarkupBuilder

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder

Groovy's `MarkupBuilder` has an `omitNullAttributes` and an `omitEmptyAttributes`. But `StreamingMarkupBuilder` doesn't.
I have tag like that one `<foo />`

Could I omit them from final output?

P.S. Could I somehow use a trick from the post [Omit empty attributes with groovy DOMBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032827/omit-empty-attributes-with-groovy-dombuilder) ?

**UPDATE:**
Example of XML

```
<A>
<Header><ID>1234</ID></Header>
<Body>
<item>
<id>001</id>
<foo />
</item>
</Body>
</A>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean?  `<foo/>` doesn't have any attributes, and seems a confusing example...

Comment: Right now I have something like that one:<a><b>...</b><foo /></a>. I wish to receive <a><b>...</b></a>. XML is a complex one and such empty tags could appears anywhere in the XML (so check one-by-one is not a case).

Comment: But neither `omitNullAttributes` nor `omitEmptyAttributes` would remove `<foo/>` from `MarkupBuilder` would it?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to remove empty elements, not attributes...

Comment: @tim_yates: I use StreamingMarkupBuilder which doesn't have such attributes. Correct updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so from the comments, it looks like you are trying to strip **empty elements**, *not* empty attributes...

If you want to strip empty nodes from xml, you would need to read it in, find the empty ones, remove them, then write it back out...

Like this example:

```
def xml = new StringWriter().with { sw ->
  new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder( sw ).with { mb ->
    a {
      b( 'tim' )
      foo()
    }
    sw.toString()
  }
}

def parser = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

def emptykids = parser.depthFirst().findAll { it.children().size() == 0 }

emptykids.each {
  parser.remove( it )
}

new XmlNodePrinter().print( parser )
```

However, if you want to not add empty elements to your XML when using StreamingMarkupBuilder, there is no way I know of of doing this.  I guess you could re-implement [the class itself](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/xml/StreamingMarkupBuilder.groovy) to handle this, but other than that, you're stuck...

It should be said however that neither of the two attributes you point out in the question will make `MarkupBuilder` do this either.  It will stop adding empty **attributes**, but it will add empty **elements**

#### Now we have an example to work to:

Try this:

```
def xml = '''|<A>
             |<Header><ID>1234</ID></Header>
             |<Body>
             |<item>
             |<id>001</id>
             |<foo />
             |</item>
             |</Body>
             |</A>'''.stripMargin()

def parser = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

parser.depthFirst().each { 
  if( it.children().size() == 0 ) {
    it.parent().remove( it )
  }
}

new XmlNodePrinter().print( parser )
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Possible issue in .depthFirst() call? My XML hierarchy is more complex (more than 1 level).

Comment: @FoxyBOA Unfortunately, unless you come up with an example that doesn't work, I can't help any more...  My psychic ability is a bit drained at the moment...

Comment: Add an example to original post.